# Cannot add a correct invoice using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, forms

I developped an invoice using ReactJS, nodejs and mysql, it have a dynamic table, as you can see the invoive component in this link : https://codeshare.io/5zqLeN

My router is :

```
exports.ajouterfact = function(req, res) {
    console.log("req", req.body);
    var today = new Date();

    var factures = {
        "Nfact": req.body.Nfact,
        "Nom": req.body.Nom,
        "Datefact": req.body.Datefact,
        "Note": req.body.Note,
        "Nomp": req.body.Nomp,
        "QuantiteF": req.body.QuantiteF,

    }
    connection.query('INSERT INTO factures SET ?', factures, function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("error ocurred", error);
            res.send({
                "code": 400,
                "failed": "error ocurred"
            })
        }
        else {
            //  console.log('The solution is: ', results);
            res.send({
                "code": 200,
                "success": "facture registered sucessfully"
            });
        }

    })
};
```

My invoice is :

[image]

When I submit it, It will be added on the database by getting:

```
req { Nfact: '15',
  Nom: 'Imen',
  Datefact: '2018-09-04T09:47:32.925Z',
  Note: 'Test',
  QuantiteF: '' }
```

The Noun of product (Nomp) is null and the quantity is ''.

But when I run my backend with Postman, it works well.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: string (json) vs integer (sql)

Comment: Can you explain more, please @xadm

Comment: You have to convert these fields to integer before using in sql statement.

Comment: How can I do it @xadm ?

Comment: `"QuantiteF": parseInt( req.body.QuantiteF ),` ?

Comment: @xadm I get  `Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list'`

Comment: check what's wrong `console.log( factures )` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179392/discussion-between-codelover-and-xadm).

Comment: show how did you updated code here (in question)